# Nvidia-smi has failed because it could't communicate with the Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 18.10, gpu

My gpu is Titan xp Geforce. 
and I just installed ubuntu 18.10. 
am I already installed the nvidia driver?

after I typed

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

and also I installed the tensorflow with conda install
after I reboot it did not reboot 
and shows this message

```
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

Comment: You need to install nvidia binary drivers first. One way is to issue this command `sudo apt install nvidia-384`. You may have different versions available.